# Is "leave" a linking verb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, linking-verbs

I am wondering, if we want to express that sth is left in a condition, for example the condition of being *idle*, can we write "sth is left idle"? Here, is the verb "left" considered a linking verb?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly write (and say) "something is left idle". In fact that's exactly the correct way to put it.

"To leave", itself, is not a linking verb, but for the purposes of your sentence, with its passive construction, you can consider "is left" (or "to be left"), together, as a linking verb, with "idle" as the [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement).

From another perspective, arguably you can also consider "is" (or "to be") as the (linking) verb, and "left idle" as an [adjective phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase), and as the subject complement. There are often many ways to parse a sentence.

In this case, however, you might want to consider it from a third angle.

Because "to leave" is transitive in its active form (it takes a direct object, not a subject complement) in the sense under consideration, on its own you shouldn't consider it a linking verb.

But either way you can think of "idle" as resultative; i.e. as a *result* of *being left*, the thing remains *idle*. And if you make your construction active, you can see that "idle" is still resultative, but "to leave" is definitely not a linking verb: "leave something idle". So, for example, *she deliberately left the machine idle*, where "deliberately" is an adverb of manner, and "idle" is a resultative complement (also called a [predicative adjective as object complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)#Predicative.2C_subject_and_object_complements)).

It's common for an adjective to act as a resultative complement. You can read more about resultatives here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. It mentions all options, it emphasises the right elements, and it adds nuance too.

Comment: @Cerberus: Then I'm happy to stop editing it, for now. ;-)

Comment: Ha, you perfectionist...